# Calling an overloaded method with the base class parameter type

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible in Kotlin to call an overloaded method using the base class type as a parameter? This is best illustrated via an example

Base Sealed Class + Derived Classes

```
    sealed class Event {
         abstract val eventId: String
    }

    data class FirstEvent(
         override val eventId: String
         val first: String
    ) : Event()

    data class SecondEvent(
         override val eventId: String
         val second: String
    ) : Event()
```

Utility Class having an overloaded method for each of the derived classes

```
    class UtilityClass {
        fun handle(event: FirstEvent) {
           ....
        }

         fun handle(event: SecondEvent) {
           ....
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to call methods of the utility class in such a way `utility.handle(FirstEvent("id", "first) as Event)` doing so is giving me the following exception

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
```

Comment: It's not possible, as there's no method `UtilityClass.handle(Event)`. You can add the method in there if you want. What are you trying to do? As this sounds like and XY problem - https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I m trying to see if the compiler or runtime is able to route to the right method call without the need to write a when statement

Comment: Got it! Kotlin doesn't support this approach and amongst other things, I think it's because each method could have a different return type.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
fun handleEvent(event: Event) {
    when (event) {
        is FirstEvent -> {
            // event is automatically casted as FirstEvent
            event.first
        }
        is SecondEvent -> ...
    }
}
```